# Spring - Reading Properties (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'name' in string value "${name}")

Tags: java, spring

I see the below the error when I tried to read properties from classpath in my Spring project using @PropertySource annotation. I have pasted my code below , please can you help in letting me know what I am missing? Thanks.

> WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization -
>   cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'customerRepository': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder
>   'name' in string value "${name}"
>
> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'customerRepository': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder
>   'name' in string value "${name}"

**AppConfig.java**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;

import com.vivek.service.CustomerService;
import com.vivek.service.CustomerServiceImpl;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.vivek")
@PropertySource("app.properties")
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer getPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer(){
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer p = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        //p.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return p;
    }

    @Bean(name="customerService")
    @Scope("prototype")
    public CustomerService getCustomerService(){
        CustomerServiceImpl service = new CustomerServiceImpl();
        //service.setRepository(getCustomerRepository());
        return service;
    }

/*  @Bean(name="customerRepository")
    public CustomerRepository getCustomerRepository(){
        CustomerRepository repository = new HibernateCustomerRepository();
        return repository;
    }*/
}
```

**Application.java**

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

import com.vivek.service.CustomerService;
import com.vivek.service.CustomerServiceImpl;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        CustomerService service = context.getBean("customerService",CustomerService.class);
        System.out.println(service);
        CustomerService service1 = context.getBean("customerService",CustomerService.class);
        System.out.println(service1);

        System.out.println(service.findAll().get(0).getFirstName());
        System.out.println(service.findAll().get(0).getLastName());
    }

}
```

**HibernateCustomerRepository.java**

```
package com.vivek.repository;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.vivek.model.Customer;

@Repository("customerRepository")
public class HibernateCustomerRepository implements CustomerRepository {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.vivek.repository.CustomerRepository#findAll()
     */
    @Value("${name}")
    private String name;

    @Override
    public List<Customer> findAll(){
        List<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();

        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setFirstName(name);
        customer.setLastName("Shah");

        customerList.add(customer);

        return customerList;
    }
}
```

**CustomerServiceImpl.java**

```
package com.vivek.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.vivek.model.Customer;
import com.vivek.repository.CustomerRepository;
import com.vivek.repository.HibernateCustomerRepository;

public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.vivek.service.CustomerService#findAll()
     * 
     */

    private CustomerRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public void setRepository(CustomerRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Customer> findAll(){
        CustomerRepository repository = new HibernateCustomerRepository();
        return repository.findAll();
    }



}
```

**app.properties**

```
name=Arnold
```

Comment: Can you try PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer instead in  your app config ?

Comment: Thanks Shiv V !! I tried it and the error is gone. However the name is printed as null . Is there anything else that i am doing wrong?

Comment: No problem. Please verify the property file is in classpath and spring is able to access the file. Check the logs for filenotfoundexception in case.

Comment: I had placed the file under sources directory , so I guess it should have found file . But I'll recheck . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to declare PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer in spring config file.

```
 <bean 
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>config.properties</value>
    </property>
 </bean>
```